# Using Loops to Keep Multiple User Input

Tags: python

I want to code a small program that **ask the user for the names of their best friends. When they are done, they press Enter, the loop stops and prints the each friend name in a numbered list.**

It should look something like this:

- Enter the names of your best friends
- Friends Name (Enter to quit): Friend1
- Friends Name (Enter to quit): Friend2
- Friends Name (Enter to quit):  Enter
- My best friends are:

  1. Friend1
  2. Friend2

Here is what I have so far, which is an incomplete draft:

```
while True:
    friendname = input("Friends Name (Enter to quit): ")
    list = str(friendname)" #something here keeps the names
    if friendname == "":
        break
print (list)
```

**The issue is, I dont know how to keep the names and then print them in a list.**

Comment: Are you expecting the user to type the names on the same line, one after the other, and then press enter to put them all in lists?

Comment: Without the user pressing enter, how would you know when they're finished entering one name versus entering multiple friends' names? Consider using a different termination condition.

Comment: One name after the other, and when they press Enter, show them all in a numbered list.

Comment: Alek, the user can enter as many names as they like. When they are done, they press Enter and the names are shown in a list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `input` doesn't stop waiting for input until the user presses `Enter`. This means your current design won't work as intended. Consider the following simple alternative:

```
friends = input("Enter your friends' names separated by a space: ").split()

print("Your friends are: {}".format(friends))
```

Here's an example:

[image]